# Google Sheets API v4 refresh token must be passed in or se t as part of setAccessToken

Tags: php, api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using *Google Sheet API V4*.

[I follows these instructions](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php) for accessing my sheet. It works well well on first day. Then second day i run again following command to run the script.

```
php quickstart.php
```

When i runs the above command it shows me following error

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught LogicException: refresh token must be passed in or se t as part of setAccessToken in C:\xampp\htdocs\sheetapi\vendor\google\apiclient\ src\Google\Client.php:258

Below is the code.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Google Sheets API PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-php-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
```

For Refresh Token Following code is used.

```
// Refresh the token if it's expired.
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
}
```

I checks the questions on SO [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314833/google-api-client-refresh-token-must-be-passed-in-or-set-as-part-of-setaccessto) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34384222/issue-with-google-api-php-client-getting-error-when-running-the-quick-start-scr). These questions providing same answer which is updated in *Sheet API V4*.

After following all above solutions i am getting the above error, How can i get rid off from this error?

Comment: what happens if you include the setOfflineAcess from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314833/google-api-client-refresh-token-must-be-passed-in-or-set-as-part-of-setaccessto)?

Comment: @noogui Offline is already set in V4. but it is giving same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46253071/4198948 :)